# how to cause a blazor foreach loop iterate when statehaschanged, even if no variable inside foreach (.. has not changed

Tags: async-await, event-handling, blazor

I have this code that is for a QuickGrid component custom paging (example from microsoft):

```
@if (pagination.TotalItemCount.HasValue)
{
    for (var pageIndex = 0; pageIndex <= pagination.LastPageIndex; pageIndex++)
    {
        var capturedIndex = pageIndex;
        <button @onclick="@(() => GoToPageAsync(capturedIndex))"
                class="@PageButtonClass(capturedIndex)"
                aria-current="@AriaCurrentValue(capturedIndex)"
                aria-label="Go to page @(pageIndex + 1)">
            @(pageIndex + 1)
        </button>
    }
}
```

At some point I call:

`<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ms-1" @onclick="@(() => { pagination.SetCurrentPageIndexAsync(0); })">Search</button>`

Even if StateHasChanged() is called after onclick but paging is not updated and It remains in page 2. So how to do anything so that foreach loop rerenders after statehaschanged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
@onclick="@(() => { pagination.SetCurrentPageIndexAsync(0); })"
```

with

```
@onclick="@(() => pagination.SetCurrentPageIndexAsync(0))"
```

Just remove the `{` `;}` and the eventhandling will honor the returned Task and await it.

Note that your current code shows a warning about "SetCurrentPageIndexAsync is not awaited", and that is precisely why your UI is not being updated.